# Python subprocess - run multiple shell commands over SSH

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I am trying to open an SSH pipe from one Linux box to another, run a few shell commands, and then close the SSH.

I don't have control over the packages on either box, so something like fabric or paramiko is out of the question.

I have had luck using the following code to run one bash command, in this case "uptime", but am not sure how to issue one command after another. I'm expecting something like:

```
sshProcess = subprocess.call('ssh ' + <remote client>, <subprocess stuff>)
lsProcess = subprocess.call('ls', <subprocess stuff>)
lsProcess.close()
uptimeProcess = subprocess.call('uptime', <subprocess stuff>)
uptimeProcess.close()
sshProcess.close()
```

What part of the subprocess module am I missing?

Thanks

```
pingtest = subprocess.call("ping -c 1 %s" % <remote client>,shell=True,stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'),stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
if pingtest == 0:
  print '%s: is alive' % <remote client>
  # Uptime + CPU Load averages
  print 'Attempting to get uptime...'
  sshProcess = subprocess.Popen('ssh '+<remote client>, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  sshProcess,stderr = sshProcess.communicate()
  print sshProcess
  uptime = subprocess.Popen('uptime', shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  uptimeProcess,stderr = uptimeProcess.communicate()
  uptimeProcess.close( )
  print 'Uptime         : ' + uptimeProcess.split('up ')[1].split(',')[0]
else:
  print "%s: did not respond" % <remote client>
```

Comment: You might like to have a look at fabric, which is a framework that already does the sort of stuff you want to do http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.8/#

Comment: I agree that Fabric would be useful. Unfortunately, I don't have control over either box, just access.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

basically if you call subprocess it creates a local subprocess not a remote one
so you should interact with the ssh process. so something along this lines:
but be aware that if you dynamically construct my directory it is suceptible of shell injection then END line should be a unique identifier
To avoid the uniqueness of END line problem, an easiest way would be to use different ssh command

```
from __future__ import print_function,unicode_literals
import subprocess

sshProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ssh',
                               '-tt'
                               <remote client>],
                               stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                               stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                               universal_newlines=True,
                               bufsize=0)
sshProcess.stdin.write("ls .\n")
sshProcess.stdin.write("echo END\n")
sshProcess.stdin.write("uptime\n")
sshProcess.stdin.write("logout\n")
sshProcess.stdin.close()


for line in sshProcess.stdout:
    if line == "END\n":
        break
    print(line,end="")

#to catch the lines up to logout
for line in  sshProcess.stdout: 
    print(line,end="")
```

Comment: I was getting an error that stdin wasn't recognized, so I added the module name. Now it just hangs until I CTRL+C it.


sshProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', remoteClient],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

sshProcess.stdin.write('ls')

sshProcess.stdin.write('echo END')
for line in sshProcess.stdout.readlines():
    if line == "END\n":
        break
    print(line)

sshProcess.stdin.write("uptime")
sshProcess.stdin.write("echo END")
for line in sshProcess.stdout.readlines():
    if line == "END\n":
        break
    print(line)

Man this formatting is a pain in the butt.

Comment: sorry to be posting in an old question, but when I try this, I get `IOError: File not open for reading` on the line `for line in stdout.readlines():` . I used `from sys import stdout`. I googled it but no luck. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: the stdout was the `sshProcess` one not `sys` one. Moreover I did test and everything did not work as expected. Now the example work

Comment: granted this is old, but an alternative to the END trick is to use sshProcess.stdin.write("logout\n") as the final input. This closes the ssh connection and removes the need for the "if...break" when printing sshProcess.stdout

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks! A little improvement:

`... Popen(['ssh', '-tt', ...` to avoid this error:

`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`