# python subprocess for multiple command in one process

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I am using subprocess to connect ssh session to remote host to execute multiple commands.

My current code:

```
 import subprocess
 import sys

 HOST="admin@10.193.180.133"
 # Ports are handled in ~/.ssh/config since we use OpenSSH
 COMMAND1="network port show"
 ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND1],
                   shell=False,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
 if result == []:
     error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
     print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
 else:
      resp=''.join(result)
      print(resp)
COMMAND2="network interface show"

 ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND2],
                   shell=False,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
 if result == []:
     error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
     print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
 else:
     resp=''.join(result)
     print(resp)
```

In above case my code asking me to enter password twice.

But what i want make is the password should be ask one time and multiple commands has to be execute.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python subprocess - run multiple shell commands over SSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900754/python-subprocess-run-multiple-shell-commands-over-ssh)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66620427/3701072 here is my take on a running multiple commands.

Answer (score 2):

You are opening two connections in your code, so it's natural that you'll have to enter a password twice.

Instead, you can open one connection and pass multiple remote commands.

```
from __future__ import print_function,unicode_literals
import subprocess

sshProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 
                               <remote client>],
                               stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                               stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                               universal_newlines=True,
                               bufsize=0)
sshProcess.stdin.write("ls .\n")
sshProcess.stdin.write("echo END\n")
sshProcess.stdin.write("uptime\n")
sshProcess.stdin.write("echo END\n")
sshProcess.stdin.close()
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19903649/2327328) for more details